# Show Message When DataSource Returns Empty for a Kendo ComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

While using the Kendo MVC Helper control & I am managing other aspects of a form using JavaScript (JS).  I have a JS reference to the Kendo DropDown control which passes 'search text' to an API call.  Obviously, the search text may return no results.

If no results are returned, I want to show a message (and/or do other stuff). However, I am having trouble finding the right event to use.

These are the only events that 'seem' useful for this purpose:

- CHANGE: Fires only when data exists and they change the drop-downs choice
- DATABOUND: Fires only if API data exists

**QUESTION:**
Using JavaScript, how do I show a message when the API call returns an empty dataset?

I will go ahead and include some code...although you don't need it to answer this particular question.

**SAMPLE MARKUP:**

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 600px">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-sm text-align">Search</span>
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("ddlMeter")
          .Filter("contains")
          .Placeholder("Type Meter Name or Number...")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .AutoBind(false)
          .MinLength(4)
          .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("findmeter", "rtf", new { area = "documents" }))
            .ServerFiltering(true))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
</div>
```

**SAMPLE JAVASCRIPT:**
This is just a sample controller...

function PageController(options) {

```
var that = this,
    empty = {},
    dictionary = {
        elements: {
            form: null,
            ddlMeter: null,
        },
        instances: {
            ddlMeter: null
        },
        selectors: {
            form: 'form',
            ddlMeter: '#ddlMeter'
        }
    };

var initialize = function (options) {
    that.settings = $.extend(empty, $.isPlainObject(options) ? options : empty);

    // Elements
    dictionary.elements.form = $(dictionary.selectors.form);
    dictionary.elements.ddlMeter = $(dictionary.selectors.ddlMeter, dictionary.elements.form);

    // Kendo Objects
    dictionary.instances.ddlMeter = dictionary.elements.ddlMeter.data('kendoComboBox');

    // Events
    dictionary.instances.ddlMeter.bind('change', that.on.change.ddlMeter);
    dictionary.instances.ddlMeter.bind('dataBind', that.on.databind.ddlMeter);
};

this.on = {
    change: {
        ddlMeter: function (e) {
            // This only fires if they CHANGE the controls choice on an existing dataset
        },
    databind: {
        ddlMeter: function (e) {
            // This wont do it if the set is empty
        }
    },
};

initialize(options);
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the `RequestEnd` event instead. If I remember correctly, you can get a handle to the datasource inside the event using the following syntax:

```
this.dataSource.data();
```

or

```
.DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("findmeter", "rtf", new { area = "documents" }))
    .Events(e=>e.RequestEnd("requestEnd"))
    .ServerFiltering(true))
```

Comment: 'DataBound' does not work.  However 'EndRequest' does.  You answer guided me towards it...so if you update your answer to reflect this link I will mark yours as correct.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd

Comment: That event is on the datasource not the combobox.

Comment: I know...but it works.  There is NO event at the ComboBox level that I can see (that actually works).  Thanks for the idea.